# Cursor too big in contentEditable div until I start typing

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Chrome, and possibly other browsers, when you first visit [my site](http://lastcalc.com/), you'll notice that the blinking cursor in the text field (actually an editable DIV) extends several pixels below the bottom of the field.  [Here](https://img.skitch.com/20120203-pg6a5mx7tttxx927gmw9c12dhd.png) is a screenshot of it.

The weird thing is that the moment you start typing the problem goes away.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have this problem too. The thing is, I switched to a contenteditable div specifically because I needed it to be single line, inline-block, to simulate a "stretchy input". So none of these answers work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Better solution will be:

Currently you have:

```
div.question.editing {
    width: 95%;
}
```

Make it block

```
div.question.editing {
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: what if I want it to be `inline-block`? `block` is out of the question for me, so this answer is good only in this specific case

Answer (score 5):

You have in your CSS class for `div.question`

`display: inline-block;`

Removing this and allowing the default `display: block;` for the div appears to resolve the issue, although I can't say I know the reasoning why.... I'd try to replace what your attempted layout is using float though to see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: Hmm, yes - that does appear to solve the problem - however it creates another one because elements that appear to the right of the div.question now appear on the next line - whereas they're supposed to be on the same line.  To try it type "2+2" and hit enter.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add another class with display inline and add to  the div tag of "2+2=4"

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully the best solution for this issue.

we may need `display:inline-block` in some cases. So, until user starts typing, we can apply style `display:block`.

***CSS3 :empty selector*** helps here...!

```
/* initially before user starts typing */

.multi-line-contenteditable:empty{
display : block;
}

/* After user types the characters */

.multi-line-contenteditable{
display : inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

- Add a min-height to the element
- Pre-populate it with a line break `<br/>`
- Change it to a multiline text box :)

Comment: Hmm, the issue isn't that the element isn't high enough though - it's height doesn't change when you start typing, only the cursor size does...

Comment: <br/> can be styled to display: none